# How can I create a connection manager and process query result in multiple ways? (Java)

Tags: java, database, postgresql, design-patterns

sorry for the long post. I will try to be as clear as possible.

I'm creating an app for my Software Engineering class and I am in front of this problem:

As suggested by one of our teachers, I should assign the responsibility of managing database resources to DAOs. I created an abstract DAO class which creates the connection to my database (it's a PostgreSQL database) to manage every connection in a single class, which opens the stream and closes it after the result of a query is consumed through an abstract method that will be implemented by many concrete DAO singleton classes. 
At the end of the post, there is an example of what I coded.

Everything seems fine to me because thanks to the inheritance I can connect several and different DAOs to the database, that is my case. 
The true point now is that I can't figure out how can I process the data inside the ResultSet, without taking care of the query that was made or what method of one of the concrete classes asked for connection.

P.S.: I tried to look for some patterns/solutions but I didn't find anything that fit my case.
P.P.S.: I know that I should use DataSource instead of DriverManager, but this is what was taught in class.

---

The abstract class Example:

```
public abstract class AbstractDAO {
  private static final String URL = "my_url";
  private static final String USR = "my_usr";
  private static final String PWD = "my_pwd";

  private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

  protected void connect(String query){
      try(Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USR, PWD);
          PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query)){
          ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
          processResult(rs);
      }catch (SQLException e){
          logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
      }
  }
  // abstract method to process atomically the result in each DAO.
  protected abstract void processResult(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException;
}
```

The concrete class Example:

```
public class ConcreteDAO extends AbstractDAO {
  private static ConcreteDAO instance = null;

  private ConcreteDAO() {
      super();
  }

  private static synchronized ConcreteDAO getInstance() {
      if (ConcreteDAO.instance == null) {
          ConcreteDAO.instance = new ConcreteDAO();
      }
      return ConcreteDAO.instance;
  }
  @Override
  protected void processResult(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
      int numCols = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
      while (rs.next()) {
          for (int i = 1; i <= numCols; i++) {
              System.out.println("\t" + rs.getString(i));
          }
          System.out.println("");
      }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String query = "select name, surname from test";
    getInstance().connect(query);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use one of the many ready-mode connection pools? Or at least the built-in  DataSource from the Postgres JDBC driver https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/ds-cpds.html

Comment: Your DAO needs to know what query was executed and what data it's handling. Otherwise it will only be able to perform generic things on it, like print out the results which is pretty useless (and you don't need a convoluted inheritance hierarchy for that). The `ConcreteDAO` isn't concrete unless you can tell what sort of data it handles.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem is not the connection method (as I said in the P.P.S, my teachers said to use Driver Manager). Maybe I wasn't clear enough. The true point of my problem is after the connection stage because I need to handle queries results and process them in different ways inside a single class, because I have different methods which calls the "connect()" method, like in the example.

Comment: @Kayaman Yeah I thought about that. I tried to make a switch, mapping the query-string I do to integers, but I didn't like what comes out. 
Obviously I know what data my ConcreteDAOs handle, eg to create an entity retrieving user's data from the database, after it logged into the system.